# How does one handle DOM events from various buttons by a single handler function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-delegation

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to use one unique function to trigger 4 different buttons to count a value (+ and -). But there are four different span values, for example, if I trigger forest it will only add or remove from forest, if I do it for town it will only trigger for town, and so on.

```js
// set inital value to zero
let count = 0;
// select value and buttons
const valueForest = document.querySelector("#valueForest");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

btns.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
    if (styles.contains("decrease")) {
      count--;
    } else if (styles.contains("increase")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
      valueForest.style.color = "green";
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      valueForest.style.color = "red";
    }
    if (count === 0) {
      valueForest.style.color = "#222";
    }
    valueForest.textContent = count;
  });
 });
```

```html
<div class="scoreDiv">
  <h3>Input below the quantity of each tile in the end of the game:</h3>
  <div class="scoreItem">
      <h4>Forest</h4>
      <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
      <span class="value" id="valueForest">0</span>
      <button class="btn increase">+</button>
      <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreItem">
      <h4>Town</h4>
      <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
      <span class="value" id="valueTown">0</span>
      <button class="btn increase">+</button>
      <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreItem">
      <h4>Production</h4>
      <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
      <span class="value" id="valueProduction">0</span>
      <button class="btn increase">+</button>
      <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreItem">
      <h4>Factory</h4>
      <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
      <span class="value" id="valueFactory">0</span>
      <button class="btn increase">+</button>
      <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please remember to actually ask a question, too. Right now, your post doesn't. Read over ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post accordingly (and remember to look at your post afterwards so you can spot and fix markup problems like your codeblock has right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, with event delegation

this way:

```js
const scoreDiv = document.querySelector('div.scoreDiv') // the parent Div

scoreDiv.onclick = e => // get all clicks everywhere upon this parent Div
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('div.scoreItem > button.btn ')) return  // ignore other clicks

  let countEl =  e.target.closest('div.scoreItem').querySelector('span.value')
    , newVal  = +countEl.textContent + (e.target.matches('.decrease') ? -1 : +1)
    ;
  countEl.style.color = (newVal > 0) ? 'green' :  (newVal < 0) ? 'red' : '#222'
  countEl.textContent = newVal;
  }
```

```css
span.value {
  display       : inline-block; 
  width         : 5em; 
  text-align    : right; 
  padding-right : .5em;
  font-weight   : bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="scoreDiv">
  <h3>Input below the quantity of each tile in the end of the game:</h3>
  <div class="scoreItem">
    <h4>Forest</h4>
    <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
    <span class="value" id="valueForest">0</span>
    <button class="btn increase">+</button>
    <h4>SOMA</h4>
</div>
  <div class="scoreItem">
    <h4>Town</h4>
    <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
    <span class="value" id="valueTown">0</span>
    <button class="btn increase">+</button>
    <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreItem">
    <h4>Production</h4>
    <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
    <span class="value" id="valueProduction">0</span>
    <button class="btn increase">+</button>
    <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="scoreItem">
    <h4>Factory</h4>
    <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
    <span class="value" id="valueFactory">0</span>
    <button class="btn increase">+</button>
    <h4>SOMA</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Explanations about

```
if (!e.target.matches('div.scoreItem > button.btn')) return
```

First of all the event handler `scoreDiv.onclick = e =>`  concern  everything inside

```js
<div class="scoreDiv"> 
  // everything inside
</div>
```

So this get any click event in this space is processed by this arrow function.
It could be a click:
on the H3 element
, or one of the span elements
, or any the H4 elements
, everything !
, even the spaces between any elements.

the event [**e**] have diffrents properties
`e.currentTarget` --> is a reference to the caller element (here it is scoreDiv [div.scoreItem])
`e.target`        --> is a reference to the element where the click happen

for this job we need to do only increment / decrement operations.
that's mean we have to ignore any click event witch is not on the plus or minus buttons.
This **8** buttons are : `<button class="btn decrease">-</button>` or `<button class="btn increase">-</button>`

All this buttons correspond to **CSS** = `div.scoreItem > button.btn`

In javascript the code for testing that is

```js
e.target.matches('div.scoreItem > button.btn')
```

will return a **boolean** value (true or false)

*There is now a strategy:* Instead of making a big

```js
if ( e.target.matches('div.scoreItem > button.btn') ) 
  { 
  //...
  // with many lines of code 
  //until the closing 
  }
// and then quit the function
```

and because this is a function we use a **[Logical NOT (!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)**
to make a direct `return` from function,  coded like that:

```
if (!e.target.matches('div.scoreItem > button.btn')) return
```

The main interest is to quickly free the event manager in case of another element (present in scoreDiv) have is own click eventHandler.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Jojo! 
Sorry for my ignorance, but what does the "!e" does?

Comment: sorry, but how the expression "if (!e.target.matches('div.scoreItem > button.btn '))" ignores other clicks? How can the scoreItem be > btn? This is quite blurry for me.

Comment: @LucasMarodindepaiva I added an explantion about that in my anwser

Answer (score 3):

Since there is nothing to add to ***Mister Jojo***'s already [perfectly answered ***event delegation*** based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375594/same-function-for-different-buttons-javascript/65375774#65375774), I will focus on an approach that sees and treats *repeatedly used DOM structures which feature a specific behavior* as ***components***

As for the OP's example there would be just a *Score Item* component which implements its specific behavior exactly once and independent from the semantics of the underlying HTML/CSS.

The amount of implemented/used JavaScript code is still small enough in comparison to what such a *Score Item* component actually is capable of.

Identifying component structures relies on `data` attributes which decouples this task from whatever provided HTML- and CSS- code/environment.

Each component encapsulates its state at initialization/creation time; thus it does not read the data from the DOM (it only does write to the latter), but it does read and write the data from/to its encapsulated state.

A component also can be configured via component specific `data` attributes for an initially displayed value as well as for distinct incrementing/decrementing values.

The color-schema for positive, negative or *Zero* values are described by component specific and `data` attribute based CSS rules; there is no reason for layout related scripting overhead ...

```js
function incrementBoundItemScore() {
  const { outputControl: ctrl, currentValue, incrementValue } = this;
  ctrl.textContent = ctrl.dataset.currentValue = this.currentValue = (currentValue + incrementValue);
}
function decrementBoundItemScore() {
  const { outputControl: ctrl, currentValue, decrementValue } = this;
  ctrl.textContent = ctrl.dataset.currentValue = this.currentValue = (currentValue + decrementValue);
}

function initializeScoreItem(rootNode) {
  const incrementControl = rootNode.querySelector('[data-increase]');
  const decrementControl = rootNode.querySelector('[data-decrease]');
  const outputControl = rootNode.querySelector('[data-output]');

  const incrementValue = parseFloat(incrementControl.dataset.value, 10);
  const decrementValue = parseFloat(decrementControl.dataset.value, 10);
  const initialValue = parseFloat(outputControl.dataset.initialValue, 10);

  const scoreItem = {
    outputControl,
    currentValue: initialValue,
    incrementValue,
    decrementValue,
  }
  outputControl.textContent = outputControl.dataset.currentValue = initialValue;

  incrementControl
    .addEventListener('click', incrementBoundItemScore.bind(scoreItem));
  decrementControl
    .addEventListener('click', decrementBoundItemScore.bind(scoreItem));
}
function initialize() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-score-item-component]')
    .forEach(initializeScoreItem);
}
initialize();
```

```css
body {
  zoom: .8;
  margin: 0;
}
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.score-group {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
.score-item {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.score-item legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.score-item strong {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: small;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

[data-output][data-current-value] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
[data-output][data-current-value="0"] {
  color: #222;
}
[data-output][data-current-value^="-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="score-board">
  <!--
  <h3>Input below the quantity of each tile in the end of the game:</h3>
  //-->
  <ul>
    <li class="score-item">
      <fieldset  data-score-item-component>
        <legend>Forest</legend>

        <div class="score-group">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-decrease
            data-value='-1'
            class="btn decrease"
          >-</button>
          <output
            name="forest-score"
            data-output
            data-initial-value="9"
          ></output>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-increase
            data-value='1'
            class="btn increase"
          >+</button>
        </div>

        <strong>Soma</strong>
      </fieldset>
    </li>
    <li class="score-item">
      <fieldset data-score-item-component>
        <legend>Town</legend>

        <div class="score-group">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-decrease
            data-value='-2'
            class="btn decrease"
          >-</button>
          <output
            name="town-score"
            data-output
            data-initial-value="0"
          ></output>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-increase
            data-value='2'
            class="btn increase"
          >+</button>
       </div>

        <strong>Soma</strong>
      </fieldset>
    </li>
    <li class="score-item">
      <fieldset data-score-item-component>
        <legend>Production</legend>

        <div class="score-group">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-decrease
            data-value='-5'
            class="btn decrease"
          >-</button>
          <output
            name="production-score"
            data-output
            data-initial-value="-10"
          ></output>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-increase
            data-value='5'
            class="btn increase"
          >+</button>
        </div>

        <strong>Soma</strong>
      </fieldset>
    </li>
    <li class="score-item">
      <fieldset data-score-item-component>
        <legend>Factory</legend>

        <div class="score-group">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-decrease
            data-value='-2'
            class="btn decrease"
          >-</button>
          <output
            name="factory-score"
            data-output
            data-initial-value="-5"
          ></output>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-increase
            data-value='1'
            class="btn increase"
          >+</button>
        </div>

        <strong>Soma</strong>
      </fieldset>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked up how to change the color directly via css and luckily **Peter Seliger** showed that.

I also added in css an `output::before {content: attr(data-value)}` allowing to directly attribute this value on the display, without JS code

This further simplifies the javascript code.

*(I also took the liberty of changing the interface a little to lighten it up completely, which is of no interest for this demonstration)*

```js
const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('#score-board')

scoreBoard.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('#score-board button')) return

  let countEl = e.target.closest('fieldset')
                        .querySelector('output[data-value]')
  countEl.dataset.value = +countEl.dataset.value
                        + (+e.target.dataset.increase)
  }
```

```css
body, textarea, input  {
  font-family : Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;
  font-size   : 12px;
  }
#score-board fieldset {
  width  : 20em;
  margin : .5em 1em;
  }
#score-board legend {
  font-size : 1.4em;
  padding   : 0 .7em;
  }
#score-board output {
  display       : inline-block; 
  font-size     : 1.4em;
  width         : 5em; 
  text-align    : right; 
  padding-right : .5em;
  color         : green;
  font-weight   : bold;
  border-bottom : 1px solid grey;
  margin        : 0 .8em 0 .2em;
  }
#score-board output::before {
  content : attr(data-value)
  }
#score-board output[data-value="0"] {
  color: #222;
  }
#score-board output[data-value^="-"] {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<section id="score-board">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Forest</legend>
    <output data-value="-10"></output>
    <button data-increase="+1">&#69717;</button>
    <button data-increase="-1">&#69714;</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Town</legend>
    <output data-value="0"></output>
    <button data-increase="+1">&#69717;</button>
    <button data-increase="-1">&#69714;</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Production</legend>
    <output data-value="-7"></output>
    <button data-increase="+1">&#69717;</button>
    <button data-increase="-1">&#69714;</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Factory</legend>
    <output data-value="5"></output>
    <button data-increase="+1">&#69717;</button>
    <button data-increase="-1">&#69714;</button>
  </fieldset>
</section>
```

Comment: ***at all*** ... I vote for this one to be the excepted answer, since it does combine the best of all until now offered approaches/techniques ... an ***event delegation based approach*** which fulfills the OP's requirements and in addition comes with ***one of the leanest possible implementations*** due to a ***much better structured markup*** in combination with ***advanced css features***.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// set inital value to zero
//let count = 0;
// select value and buttons
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

btns.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
    const SectionValue = e.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('span');
    var count = Number( SectionValue.innerHTML );
    if (styles.contains("decrease")) {
      count--;
    } else {
      count++;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        SectionValue.style.color = "green";
    } else if (count < 0) {
        SectionValue.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        SectionValue.style.color = "#222";
    }
    SectionValue.innerHTML = count;
  });
 });
```

```html
    <div class="scoreDiv">
        <h3>Input below the quantity of each tile in the end of the game:</h3>
        <div class="scoreItem">
            <h4>Forest</h4>
            <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
            <span class="value" id="valueForest">0</span>
            <button class="btn increase">+</button>
            <h4>SOMA</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="scoreItem">
            <h4>Town</h4>
            <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
            <span class="value" id="valueTown">0</span>
            <button class="btn increase">+</button>
            <h4>SOMA</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="scoreItem">
            <h4>Production</h4>
            <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
            <span class="value" id="valueProduction">0</span>
            <button class="btn increase">+</button>
            <h4>SOMA</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="scoreItem">
            <h4>Factory</h4>
            <button class="btn decrease">-</button>
            <span class="value" id="valueFactory">0</span>
            <button class="btn increase">+</button>
            <h4>SOMA</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: When posting answer, please also describe what your code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: The code resolves the pointer problem by replacing valueForest with SectionValue. I also fixed the conditions to what I would call standard.